# Looping through documents in mongodb through robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I have imported the `MongoDBLibrary` and We can retrieve the data from MongoDB in Robot Framework using the below keywords

```
Retrieve All Mongodb Records
Retrieve Mongodb Records With Desired Fields
Retrieve Some Mongodb Records
```

After the records got by using one of the above keywords, i want to iterate through the documents and do some validation.

My Query will be as

`${result} =    Retrieve Mongodb Records With Desired Fields    ${MDBName}   {MDBCollection}    ${mQuery}    ${mRFields}    ${misReturnID}`

sample output will be as: ${result} contains

`[(u'profileDetails', {u'basicDetails': {u'customerCode': u'C037799'}})][(u'profileDetails', {u'basicDetails': {u'customerCode': u'C000092'}})]`

in above result -

`[(u'profileDetails', {u'basicDetails': {u'customerCode': u'C037799'}})]` is first record

`[(u'profileDetails', {u'basicDetails': {u'customerCode': u'C000092'}})]` is second record

I want to separate the above `result` into a `list`.

I tried to catch the `result` as `list`, it gave an error 
`Cannot set variable '@{result}': Expected list-like value, got string`

How I can iterate through the documents/records came as result.

Comment: Can you tell me what value is stored in "${result}" variable ?

Comment: Hi Akash , `${result}` have the value `[(u'profileDetails', {u'basicDetails': {u'customerCode': u'C037799'}})][(u'profileDetails', {u'basicDetails': {u'customerCode': u'C000092'}})]`

Comment: and how should your modified result ( list ) look like?

Comment: Either like comma separated. `[(u'profileDetails', {u'basicDetails': {u'customerCode': u'C037799'}})],[(u'profileDetails', {u'basicDetails': {u'customerCode': u'C000092'}})]' then I can take the each record and process

Comment: than the below code should help, i think. Just in case you want to retain the square brackets you can replace them with "]<identifier>" and then split with <identifier>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your value returned is in string format, I tried the below code snippet to manipulate your result string to get a list.

```
*** Settings ***
Library  String
Library  Collections

*** Variables ***
${result}  [(u'profileDetails', {u'basicDetails': {u'customerCode': u'C037799'}})][(u'profileDetails', {u'basicDetails': {u'customerCode': u'C000092'}})]

*** Test Cases ***
Manipulate String and convert to list
    ${result1}=  Replace String  ${result}  ][   ]],[[
    @{res_list}=  Split String  ${result1}  ],[
    Remove Values from list  ${res_list}    ${EMPTY}
    Log To Console  ${res_list}


##Output : ["[(u'profileDetails', {u'basicDetails': {u'customerCode': u'C037799'}})]", "[(u'profileDetails', {u'basicDetails': {u'customerCode': u'C000092'}})]", "[(u'profileDetails', {u'basicDetails': {u'customerCode': u'C037855'}})]", "[(u'profileDetails', {u'basicDetails': {u'customerCode': u'C037784'}})]", "[(u'profileDetails', {u'basicDetails': {u'customerCode': u'C037642'}})]"]
```

Thanks Sarada for improving the answer to make it specific to your use case!

Comment: hi waman, this will not work, because in some of the inputs inside array `[..]` also comes not only at start and end

Comment: is there are particular format of these records? so that we can manipulate them based on a pattern

Comment: Hi waman, i found the solution by changing your logic little bit based on, how my result will be always. can i edit your answer?

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8viqm.jpg)*** Settings ***
Library  String
Library  Collections

*** Variables ***
${result}  [(u'profileDetails', {u'basicDetails': {u'customerCode': u'C037799'}})][(u'profileDetails', {u'basicDetails': {u'customerCode': u'C000092'}})]

*** Test Cases ***
Manipulate String and convert to list
    ${result}  Evaluate  [list(x) for x in $result]
    Log  ${result}

Comment: can you please add some explanation to clarify your answer.